# How to completely remove tthe topbar in VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation, when I hover the mouse at the edge of the screen, the topbar shows up and it is starting to be annoying! Is there any way to completely disable the topbar when I am in full screen mode. I've already hidden the bar when unpinned, but it doesn't change anything, if I hover the edge, the topbar shows up.

Comment: That toolbar allows you to manage machines (suspend, restart a stuck machine) and add devices (USB pass through and such). I wonder if (expect that) this is the reason it cannot be permanently disabled.

Comment: @John I understand but it could be possible to use shortcuts instead...

Comment: I have not seen an ability to make shortcuts of the menu items - they are integrated into the program.

Comment: Which VMware product are you asking about?  Are you asking about VMware Workstation Professional, VMware Workstation Player, or VMware Fusion?  If VMware Fusion, what do you mean by "MacOS for example"?  macOS is the *only* available host OS.  Or if you mean VMware Workstation, then macOS is not a supported guest OS.

Comment: Anyway, in VMware Fusion, [per the docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-4C1EE43F-DA60-4172-A179-8A42546E794F.html), it sounds like you can disable the menu bar by pressing  Command+Shift+M.  In VMware Workstation Professional, you can use "Exclusive Mode" to restrict input to the guest OS, which would prevent triggering the full screen toolbar.

Comment: @jamesdlin i am using VMware Workstation Pro, I should have told it... But this is exactly what I am looking for, so if you write an answer, I will validate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VMware Workstation Professional, you can use "Exclusive Mode" to restrict input to the guest OS, which would prevent triggering the full screen toolbar.